# Why won't button text show on the button in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a registration program in tkinter python. The program works fine, but the buttons have no text. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title("Registration Form")

Fullname = StringVar()
Email = StringVar()
var = IntVar()
c = StringVar()
var1 = IntVar()


def database():
    name1 = Fullname.get()
    email = Email.get()
    gender = var.get()
    country = c.get()
    prog = var1.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tennis.db')
    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (Fullname TEXT,Email TEXT,Gender TEXT,country TEXT,Programming TEXT)')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Student (FullName,Email,Gender,country,Programming) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',
               (name1, email, gender, country, prog,))
    conn.commit()


label_0 = Label(root, text="Registration form", width=20, font=("bold", 20))
label_0.place(x=90, y=53)

label_1 = Label(root, text="FullName", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
label_1.place(x=80, y=130)

entry_1 = Entry(root, textvar=Fullname)
entry_1.place(x=240, y=130)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Email", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
label_2.place(x=68, y=180)

entry_2 = Entry(root, textvar=Email)
entry_2.place(x=240, y=180)

label_3 = Label(root, text="Gender", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
label_3.place(x=70, y=230)

Radiobutton(root, text="Male", padx=5, variable=var, value=1).place(x=220, y=230)
Radiobutton(root, text="Female", padx=20, variable=var, value=2).place(x=290, y=230)

label_4 = Label(root, text="City", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
label_4.place(x=70, y=280)

list1 = ['Africa', 'Nigeria', 'Oshawa', 'Other'];

droplist = OptionMenu(root, c, *list1)
droplist.config(width=15)
c.set('select your city')
droplist.place(x=240, y=280)

label_4 = Label(root, text="Skill Level", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
label_4.place(x=85, y=330)
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()

Checkbutton(root, text="Beginner", variable=var1).place(x=200, y=330)

Checkbutton(root, text="Intermiadiate", variable=var2).place(x=280, y=330)

Checkbutton(root, text="Advanced", variable=var3).place(x=390, y=330)

def printdatshuff():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tennis.db')
    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Student")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    for r in result:
        print(r)

johy = Button(root, text='Submit', width=20, bg='brown', fg='white', command=database)
johy.place(x=180, y=380)
johy1 = Button(root, text='See all', width=20, bg='brown', fg='white', command=printdatstuff)
johy1.place(x=180, y=400)

root.mainloop()
```

The end of the program is where the buttons code is located. I specified that the button shows text but it won't. If anyone knows how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Jamal

Comment: Thats not the solution because I added the buttons

Comment: It would really help  if you could create a [mcve] that didn't rely on an external database -- just change the program to use some static data from a list or dictionary or something like that.

Comment: Are you running on OSX?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the foreground to white, which is also the default background color on OSX. OSX doesn't allow you to change the background color. Therefore you have white text on a white background.

If you change the `fg` attribute to something other than "white", you'll see the text.